# Graphql - what constitutes an operation having a unique name?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am having trouble making my code generator run. The reason given is that Not all operations have an unique name: AllIssueGroups.

I am not clear on what an "operation" is exactly.

I have a single issueGroup.resolver, a single issueGroup.service and then more than one component in the front end that tries to read from AllIssueGroups, using the following gql:

```
const _ = gql`
  query AllIssueGroups {
      allIssueGroups {
        id
        title
        description
        issues
      }
    }
```

In each react component, I only define this const once, but I'm wondering if graphql thinks each of those is an "operation".

My resolver has:

```
@Query(() => [IssueGroup])
        async allIssueGroups() {
            return await this.issueGroupService.getAllIssueGroups()
        }
```

My service has:

```
async getAllIssueGroups() {
    return (await prisma.issueGroup.findMany({orderBy: {title: 'asc'}}))
  }
```

Each of the service and resolver is defined once, only.

Where can I find the definition of "operation" for graphql's purposes? I can't figure out why it thinks it is not uniquely defined.

In my graphql.tsx, the AllIssueGroup entries are not duplicated.

How can I find what is causing the codegen to think that it is not uniquely named?